# Custom Calculation Script (javascript) for a pdf form

Tags: javascript, variables, pdf, dynamic

Question:
event.value = this.getField("TotalPaperTowelCostsperYear").value  / 2;

Above is the equation used to get the correct value as is for the handling cost.

Is there a way to add a fuction to the above string to allow a user to enter there own value for "TotalPaperTowelCostsperYear" and have it be used in the equation instead.

for example: use the above equation, unless the user enters there own value.

This is in a dynamic PDF form - if user knows actual handling costs figure that would be preferred over the estimated handling costs which is figured by an equation of 50% of the total paper towel costs per year

Comment: Get the value fro any input filed if you giving that in the UI..

Answer (score 0):

Overriding calculated results is very tricky, and difficult to catch.

It is more recommended to add a checkbox stating something like "actual handling cost", and evaluate it in the calculation (not running it when the checkbox is clicked). The code could then look like this (you may have to adjust the field names):

```
if (this.getField("ActualHandlingCost_ckb").value != "Off") {
event.target.readonly = false ;
} else {
event.target.readonly = true ;
event.value = this.getField("TotalPaperTowelCostsperYear").value / 2 ;
}
```

It is best practice to make fields with a calculated result read-only, because any entered value would become overwritten immediately.

An additional note: in order to make the form work as good as possible, it is best practice to consolidate all calculation scripts into one single script, which then would be assigned to a hidden field which is not even involved in the calculations. The PDF/Acrobat Field Event Sequence and Calculation Sequence make sure that the calculations are executed. This approach will also give you maximum control over the calculations.